# POCO M3 Pro 5g not booting up after unexpected shutdown. It does not charge as well

Tags: charging, boot, xiaomi, miui

I was using my phone scrolling on Facebook then it suddenly shuts down. After that I tried to boot it but after holding the power button for 15 secs It shows that its out of battery. but I know my battery life was at 98% cause I just finished charging.

1 day has passed since.

**Here's what It tried so far but failed:**

1. I charge my phone but the charging screen does not appear. but it only shows the empty battery screen.
2. Tried to hard reset by holding the power button and volume down.
3. Drain the battery for 1 day then booting it.
4. Boot it while charging.
5. Hard reset while charging.
6. Tried to charge it for up to 2hrs then boot it.

Can someone tell me what's the the problem and how I can fix it?

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4465909

Comment: I was the one who ask this one. Wanted to get answers from multiple channels.